# Diferença entre tipo text e tipo varchar no SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tipagem, text, varchar

Qual a diferença de usar o tipo text ao invés do tipo `varchar` para guardar informações no banco de dados?

Existe algum problema de performance? Pois tenho uma tabela no banco que possui uma coluna *text* e ela da varias vezes erro de *timeout*.

Comment: O seu problema certamente não está no tipo de dados. Fez um teste transformando a coluna em `VARCHAR` e ver o que acontece?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`TEXT` não tem um limite específico de tamanho além do máximo do banco de dados. Ele é armazenado na área específica para *blobs* já que a expectativa é que ele será grande.

`VARCHAR` **pode** ter um limite de tamanho e é armazenado direto na linha de dados (a não ser que ultrapasse um limite, acho que 8KB). `VARCHAR(MAX)` é essencialmente o mesmo que `TEXT`

Essencialmente não há grandes problemas de performance na maioria das situações. Pode haver diferenças se estiver no *blob* já que é uma indireção. Mas também pode ajudar outras coisas. Mas esta não é a questão.

A recomendação atual é usar o `VARCHAR`. `TEXT` pode até mesmo ser removido em futuras versões, [segundo a Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Você deveria converter esta coluna por causa disto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estava lendo a respeito e me deparei com uma informação que no meu ver é importante, a questão do índice, não sei no SQLServer como é mas no caso do MySQL diz que não dá pra colocar index em campo text mas no varchar(x) sim... seria interessante falar sobre isso, fiquei curioso no caso do SQLServer

Comment: @Marcelo é interessante vou deixar a nora pelo seu comentário mesmo, até porque esse é um tipo que não deveria ser usado de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 8):

Considerando que VARCHAR(MAX) é quase a mesma coisa que TEXT. A diferença básica é que o tipo TEXT sempre vai ser armazenado em áreas de armazenamento de blob e o varchar sempre tentará armazenar os dados diretamente nas linhas, exceto caso ele exceda o limite de 8k e daí ele será armazenado como blob.

O uso do LIKE é idêntico com ambos os tipos. Uma funcionalidade adicional que o VARCHAR permite é que você possa utilizá-lo em comparadores **=** e **GROUP BY**. Mas se você tiver muitos dados nesses VARCHAR pode ter sérios problemas de performance.

Se utilizar Like, Full Text Index e CONTAINS eles se comportam da mesma forma.

Se for fazer consultas nesses campos e eles tenham uma grande quantidade de dados, o recomendado é o Full Text Index.

Fonte: [Esta resposa do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server) do [Robin Day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40655/robin-day)

Answer (score 6):

Text:

Dados não Unicode de comprimento variável na página de código do servidor e com um comprimento máximo de cadeia de caracteres de 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647). Quando a página de código de servidor usar caracteres de dois bytes, o armazenamento ainda será de 2.147.483.647 bytes. Dependendo da cadeia de caracteres, o tamanho do armazenamento pode ser menor que 2.147.483.647 bytes.

Varchar:

Dados de cadeia de caracteres não Unicode de comprimento variável. n define o comprimento da cadeia de caracteres e pode ser um valor de 1 a 8.000. max indica que o tamanho de armazenamento máximo é 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). O tamanho de armazenamento é o comprimento real dos dados inseridos + 2 bytes. Os sinônimos de ISO para varchar são char varying ou character varying.

Fonte:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187752.aspx