# erro: "table vendas has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied"

Tags: sql, sqlite

Criei a seguinte tabela em sql

```
CREATE TABLE vendas  
    (  
     ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),  
     Empresa VARCHAR (20),  
     Modelo  TEXT,  
     Preco REAL,
     Kilometragem REAL,
     Ano INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    );
```

Coloquei como chave primaria a coluna ID que esta com uma propriedade IDENTITY

Pelo o que eu pesquisei, ao inserir uma nova tupla na tabela eu posso omitir o campo ID porque ele eh auto-gerado, porem fiz a inserção.

```
INSERT INTO vendas VALUES ("Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017)
```

e retorna o erro

```
table vendas has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied: INSERT INTO vendas VALUES ("Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017)
```

Alguem pode me ajudar a solucionar esse problema, por gentileza?

Pessoal, fiz conforme o amigo guastallaigor me auxiliou, porem agora que eu fiz a inserções surgiu outro problema no campo id. Só esta indo NULL pra esse campo.

[image: tabela final apos os inserts]

Comment: qual é o banco ?

Comment: ID não é autoincrementado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente algo assim se o ID estiver de forma incremental no banco:

```
INSERT INTO vendas (Empresa, Modelo, Preco, Kilometragem, Ano) VALUES ("Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017)
```

Caso contrário, tente no momento colocar um ID manualmente para ver se funciona:

```
INSERT INTO vendas VALUES (1, "Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017)
```

**EDIT:** No caso dos ID's ficarem nulos, provavelmente faltou o `AUTOINCREMENT` ao criar a tabela `vendas` em questão.

Supondo pela imagem que o banco é SQLite, não é possível realizar um `ALTER TABLE`. Desta forma, se puder o mais fácil é dropar toda a tabela (`DROP TABLE vendas`) e criá-la novamente, algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE vendas  
(  
 ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) AUTOINCREMENT,  
 Empresa VARCHAR (20),  
 Modelo  TEXT,  
 Preco REAL,
 Kilometragem REAL,
 Ano INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Caso contrário, deve-se criar uma nova tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE vendasaux  
(  
 ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) AUTOINCREMENT,  
 Empresa VARCHAR (20),  
 Modelo  TEXT,  
 Preco REAL,
 Kilometragem REAL,
 Ano INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Depois inserir todos os registros da tabela `vendas` na tabela `vendasaux`:

```
INSERT INTO vendasaux (Empresa, Modelo, Preco, Kilometragem, Ano) SELECT Empresa, Modelo, Preco, Kilometragem, Ano from vendas;
```

Em seguida, pode agora dropar a tabela `vendas`:

`DROP TABLE vendas`

E por fim, renomear a tabela `vendasaux` para `vendas`

```
ALTER TABLE vendasaux RENAME TO vendas
```

**Obs:** Não vou conseguir testá-los agora, mas creio que funcionará, qualquer problema envie nos comentários que auxilio posteriormente.

Comment: funcionou a primeira alternativa. Muito obrigado

Comment: Olá, por nada. Se funcionou aceite minha pergunta como a correta por gentileza para que auxilie outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. Obrigado.

Comment: surgiu outro problema, voce pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sim, no caso seu ID não está de forma auto incremental. Faltou adicionar o AUTOINCREMENT ao criar a tabela na coluna ID. Provavelmente isto não será possível ser alterado com o comando ALTER TABLE no caso do SQLite, é possível dropar a tabela e criá-la com a propriedade AUTOINCREMENT?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Ao executar a query sem informar o nome das colunas, o banco não tem como saber qual o valor deverá ser inserido em qual coluna. No código:

```
INSERT INTO vendas VALUES ("Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017)
```

Ele poderia tentar inserir "Movidas" na coluna ID por exemplo.

Você só consegue omitir o nome das colunas, se tiver um valor para cada na query.

Sendo assim, você precisa informar o nome das colunas:

```
Insert into vendas (Empresa,Modelo,Preco,Kilometragem,Ano) values ("Movidas","RENAULT SANDERO 1.6 EXPRESSION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL", 36590.0,25.002,2017);
```

> Observações:

- No campo `Modelo` você está usando `Text` que é recomendado somente para textos muito grandes, pois é armazenado na área de blobs. O ideal seria `Varchar`. ([Veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44351/69359))
- No campo `Ano` você está usando `Integer` que pode armazenar um número muito grande (2.147.483.647) o que é totalmente desnecessário. Poderia ser apenas um `NUMERIC(4,0)`, pelo menos até o ano 9999... depois disso deixa que outro programador resolva =]
- Sobre os outros campos, não sei qual base você está usando, também não sei a especificação do `REAL`, então não vou entrar na questão.

Comment: Muito obrigado por suas dicas, vou aplicar elas.

Comment: Disponha, marque a questão que resolveu seu problema, e se desejar avalie-as. Faça o [Tour] para ver como funciona a comunidade