# Qual o tipo de dados para aceitar qualquer tamanho?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tipagem

Qual tipo de dado posso usar para armazenar texto de forma "dinâmica" no SQL Server?

Sei que `CHAR` e `VARCHAR` são tipos de dados caractere, a diferença é que `CHAR` é um tipo de dado de **comprimento fixo** e `VARCHAR` é de **comprimento variável até 255**. estou certo?

Agora se eu quiser escrever um texto de **x** caracteres maior que 255, qual tipo de dado devo usar?

Comment: Defina "dinâmica". `VARCAHR` aceita até 2GB.

Comment: Como o Maniero disse, realmente não é só 255 o varchar, 4000 já um valor bem grande, mas se precisar mais que isso pode usar varchar(max)

Comment: se é dinâmico só posso pensar em `varchar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se por dinâmica quer dizer aceitar um tamanho qualquer, o tipo `VARCHAR` já é o que deseja, e ele permite que você especifique um valor de 1 até 8000. Se você não especificar nada o padrão é 8000 e não 255. Mas se quiser mais do que isto ele pode chegar até 2GB, basta especificar assim:

```
VARCHAR(max)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/VarcharMax.sql).

Quando faz isto a forma como o dado é gravado muda um pouco e pode ter implicações de performance. Mais pode ser visto em [Diferença entre tipo text e tipo varchar no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44348/101).

Só se atente que isto é a quantidade de bytes e não de caracteres, existem codificações que um caractere pode até mesmo ter 4 bytes.